# Read id3 tag mp3 in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, mp3, custom-post-type, custom-wordpress-pages

How to get the tags from of the mp3 file in Wordpress:

Example:

1. Artist
2. Album
3. Genre
4. Size
5. Name of mp3 file

Te custom post is Mp3s

Comment: One of the top Google results: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_read_audio_metadata

Comment: I have a plugin for this, in addition to the stuff on codex. https://wordpress.org/plugins/mmww/